# Is it possible to have a **'Graded Color Scale"** to highlight the 6 previous cells?

Tags: excel

I want to highlight the 6 previous cells by using an ISBLANK" statement **=IF(ISBLANK(V4),"",TODAY()-V4)**. Is it possible to have a **'Graded Color Scale"** to highlight the 6 previous cells? I'm using **'mixed cell references to Cond. Format a row' with the 'active cell' to the upper right**...

Comment: I have tried to upload the "ProblemExample.xlsx, but cannot.    Perhaps by rewording the question...   For column Z, 'Days Past Due', =IF(ISBLANK(V4),"",TODAY()-V4); For column V, 'Scheduled Payment', Date Format.  I wish to format V thru Z, with a 'Graded Color Scale" working off of column Z.  So as the days go by, column Z gets a darker shade of red, and also the cells in row V thru Z (working off of Z) will be the same shade of red.

Comment: Thank you immensely pnuts!!!!!  Though unfortunately it wasn't the answer I was looking for, due my lack of knowledge VBA.  I either have to learn VBA or think of another line of attack...   Thank you...